# Show an Android App running on Browser

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app for my client. My client doesn't have an Android device. So I want to show my app running on a browser. I want to upload the app to a demo URL and want to sent the URL to my client so that we he can test my app.

If anyone have a solution, please help.

Comment: https://www.manymo.com/ may be answer

Comment: Is you application a native android app or mobile web app?

Comment: Thanks! My app is a mobile web app.

Comment: @Rick You just loading a web page in a android web view/ you need to do native functions with application

Comment: @virendrao manymo.com worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try https://appetize.io.

Just upload apk and share link obtained with your client.

Answer (score 2):

better way is to ask your client to install [bluestack](http://www.bluestacks.com/) software and than send him apk. He can install it on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to make a HTML/Web Application.

For this you mainly have to use JavaScript (for logic) and of course HTML for design, but you cannot just run an APK in a browser.